# a frame - how to click on a box and set function

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want it so that when I click on a box in a-scene it runs a function

```
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    console.log('This element was clicked!');
});
```

I tried this but it is not working

Also, you can see https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html

Comment: Have you tried it on the first `p` element? Because your code only affects the first `p` element, not all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS code, should fix your problem:

```
const paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (paragraph of paragraphs) {
  paragraph.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log("Hello it worked!")
 })
}
```